# python variable is not getting interpreted thus mysql statement is failing

Tags: python

i have a python variable which is mysql job index as seen below:

```
index_id = 14186857
```

if i will execute a mysql statment using python "cursor.execute" with that specific index_id directly

i.e specifying the  number 14186857 in the query and not using the variable index_id

The statment is running as expected as seen below:

```
cursor.execute("select  id_job,derived_es from job_table  where db_inx=14186857")
```

Then fatching the output to a variable:

```
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

if i will do the same thing specifying the variable name index_id and not  14186857 directly

cursor.execute("select  id_job,derived_es from job_table  where db_inx=index_id")

I am getting the below error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'index_id' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: `cursor.execute("select  id_job,derived_es from job_table  where db_inx={0:}".format(index_id))`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the variable inside the quotes.
Try this out:

```
cursor.execute("select id_job,derived_es from job_table where db_inx={}".format(index_id))
```